# Magento 1.9 - Add multiple product in one click in "Add to Cart" inside magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, php, addtocart, product-view

I working in view.phtml and my project is can add in the cart two or more products in only one click. I explain my project...

In the product details we have a normal product and the button add to cart In the same page i would recall another simple/virtual product with a variable. So i would that when the customer push on "add to cart" in checkout there will be two product added simultaneously.

How can I do? What files can I touch?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out how did the accessories products works ?

Comment: It's not a duplicate because i would do this operation inside magento and not outside. Not exactly, where to look? In the abstract.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to achieve this might be to just add a hidden input to your product/view.phtml (inside the #product-addtocart-form), like

```
<input type="hidden" name="related_product" value="17,133,87"/>
```

... where 17,133,87 is a comma-separated list of the product ID's to add.

Basically, looking at the code in CartController::addAction(), it all comes down to using the Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->addProductsByIds($arrayofproductids) method you could of course apply almost anywhere in code

+++ edited for improved flexibility +++

However if you need to apply any further logic on which products to add additionally or want to change the quantities you will have to set up a custom module with an event observer listening to checkout_cart_product_add_after event. You will find loads of hints how to do this on google.

In your event observer method you can best use

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $qty);

hope this helps ;)

Comment: Man, you're great!!! Thank you!! :D One more questione please. If I want to add three differen inputs with a single different value how can i do? Ah, sorry, one more question. When I add to cart two products at the same time does not show me the same quantity. How do I connect the same quantity for both of the products?

Comment: For the first question...because when i try to add to cart with two input of related product with two different value, cart just adds only one related product and not two...why? Thanks again.

Comment: if you use inputs like this '<input name="myinputname" value="1" /><input name="myinputname" value="2"/>' the second "myinputname" input value will overwrite the first one in $_POST. You should use input names like array indexes.

Comment: Another drawback for your scenario is that the CartController::addAction() only accepts comma-separated values and not array-formed. so unfortunately you can't set up your input fields like <input type="hidden" name="related_product[]" value="17"/><input type="hidden" name="related_product[]" value="133"/>, which would form the $_POSTed data as array.

Comment: Perfect man, you're very clear. Thanks again. One last question...for the quantity...if i would connect the same quantity of the simple product in product details with the related_product when push on addtocart, I have to create a custom module or there is a short way?

Comment: no, you'll need a custom module for that

Comment: Ok, thank you man. Sorry, when write <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="BundleId" /> with the id of bundle product, add to cart not function and when i try to add the products, the cart is ever empty, why this? I can't select id of bundle product in related_product? Thanks

Comment: No this will not work. BUT you can of course set up a bundle product with the name of your original visible product and add all the other products you want to sell silently to the bundle too. You will just have to hide them from display. This would be a pretty simple workaround to achieve the quantity-problem from above.